# Jmeter test scenario setup with target transactions per hour

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

My Jmeter script have 2 requests Login and Logout with response time around 13-15 sec together (Login is 12-14 sec and Logout is 0.5sec). I need to run these 2 requests one after other to reach N transactions(for each request exactly) in one hour.So together 2N transactions/hour. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach is just to [increase number of threads](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users) in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group). If 1 user can execute both requests in 15 seconds it means that he can execute 4 requests per minute or 240 requests per hour.

However given your response times are fluctuating between 13 and 15 you might want to reduce JMeter's throughput slightly using i.e. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-throughput) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)